# Что значат символы |\. в регулярке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Что значат символы `|\.` в регулярке
CODE

```
JS
/[0-9]|\./;
```

Comment: Любая цифра или символ точки (`.`)

Comment: Вертикальная палка означает "или". Написано в каждом введении в регулярки.

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: "\" перед точкой используется для экранирования символа ".", т.к. в regex точка является спец символом, обозначающим любой символ (включая обычную точку), поэтому для указания на необходимость отображения именно точки, а не любого символа, приходится экранировать символ ".".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это регулярное выражение означает, что допустима любая цифра или символ точки (`.`).